# how to link the cells with numbers? python 3 (I tried zip function and another ways)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, python-2.7, sorting

I'm attempting to replace each zero into the specific odd number in ascending order. For instance: I have a raw with this list of lists [[0], [0, 0], [0,0,0] and etc.] and I need to get this: [[1], [3,5], [7,9,11], [13,15,17,19] and etc.]

```
def x(n):
    obj = iter(list(range(1, 100, 2)))
    odds = list(range(1, 100, 2))
    a =[y*[0] for y,x in enumerate(odds,1)]
    for i in range(0,50):
        a[i] = next(obj)
    return odds
print(x(10))
```

I need a small hint. How continue/fix this code.

Comment: I don't see any `[[0], [0, 0], [0,0,0] and etc.]` input in here... so what is the question about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're trying to use an iterator...

```
#this gives you your zero lists...
def zero(n):
    return [[0] * i for i in range(1, n)]

z = zero(5) # this gives the same input as what you show in your example

x = iter(range(1, 1000, 2)) # you should calc and be sure 1000 is big enough
replacement = [[next(x) for i in chunk if i is 0] for chunk in z]
```

This uses something called list comprehension.  The function uses list comprehension to create your initial list, and the last line uses it to create the final answer. I'll add a second example, more simple, in a moment.

Here's the simpler solution:

```
def xx(ll):
    obj = iter(range(1, 1000, 2))
    for chunk in ll:
        for i in range(len(chunk)):
            if chunk[i] is 0:
                chunk[i] = next(obj)
    return ll

def zero(n):
    return [[0] * i for i in range(1, n)]

zeros = zero(5)
print(zeros)
result = xx(zeros)
print(result)
```

And the output:

```
[[0], [0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[1], [3, 5], [7, 9, 11], [13, 15, 17, 19]]
```

Again, the `xx()` function uses an iterator to pull out the odd numbers. I did it that way since I'm guessing that's part of what you want to see.  From there I step through each chunk of the master list, which is another smaller list. For each smaller list, I check to see if the value is zero, and if it is, I replace it with the next value from the iterator object.  Finally, the updated master list gets returned.

On a side note, one nice thing about this implementation is that, if the inputted master list did not include only zeroes, this code would replace only the zeros, which is where I thought you were going with this at first, till I saw how simple your input data set it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something as simple as this:

```
zeroes = [[0], [0, 0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0,0]]

count = 1
for lst in zeroes:
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        lst[i] = count
        count += 2

print(zeroes)
# [[1], [3, 5], [7, 9, 11], [13, 15, 17, 19]]
```

Which just updates the nested list of zeroes with odd numbers, based off a counter that increments in `2`.

You could also do something more complicated like this, which uses iterators and `itertools` functions:

```
import itertools

def x(n):
    # get the zeroes sublists
    zeroes = [i * [0] for i in range(1, n+1)]

    # get the length of the flattened list above
    odd_len = len(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zeroes)))

    # get the odd numbers
    odd_numbers = [i for i in range(1, odd_len * 2, 2)]

    # check they are the same length
    assert(len(odd_numbers) == odd_len)

    # convert to iterator
    odd_numbers = iter(odd_numbers)

    # loop over the zeroes
    for lst in zeroes:

        for i in range(len(lst)):

            # update the zeroes with the odd numbers
            lst[i] = next(odd_numbers)

    return zeroes

>>> print(x(4))
[[1], [3, 5], [7, 9, 11], [13, 15, 17, 19]]

>>> print(x(10))
[[1], [3, 5], [7, 9, 11], [13, 15, 17, 19], [21, 23, 25, 27, 29], [31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41], [43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55], [57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71], [73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89], [91, 93, 95, 97, 99, 101, 103, 105, 107, 109]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works on arbitrary depth list-of-list-of-list...s. It uses `itertools.count`, list comprehension and recursion.

```
import random
import itertools

def create(minchld = 2, mxchld = 4, p0 = 0.5, mxdpth = 4):
    return [0 if mxdpth==0 or random.random() < p0 else create(minchld, mxchld, p0, mxdpth-1)
            for i in range(random.randint(minchld, mxchld))]

def fill(zeros):
    odd = itertools.count(start=1, step=2)
    def replace(zeros):
        return [next(odd) if i==0 else replace(i) for i in zeros]
    return replace(zeros)

zeros = create()
print(zeros)
print(fill(zeros))
```

Sample runs:

```
# [[0, 0, [0, 0, 0]], 0, [0, 0, [[0, 0, [0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0], 0, 0], 0, 0], 0], 0]
# [[1, 3, [5, 7, 9]], 11, [13, 15, [[17, 19, [21, 23]], [[25, 27, 29], 31, 33], 35, 37], 39], 41]

# [0, [0, [0, [0, 0]]]]
# [1, [3, [5, [7, 9]]]]

# [[[0, [0, [0, 0]], [[0, 0, 0, 0], 0], [[0, 0], 0]], 0, 0, [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]], 0, 0]], 0]
# [[[1, [3, [5, 7]], [[9, 11, 13, 15], 17], [[19, 21], 23]], 25, 27, [[[29, 31, 33], [35, 37, 39, 41], [43, 45, 47], [49, 51, 53]], 55, 57]], 59]
```